# Spring MVC Thymelaf Fragment Issue

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

I am building some web application with `Spring MVC 4.2` and `Thymeleaf 2.1`.

I am using [this](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/) admin dashboard template. I created Thymeleaf fragment "main" for navigation and sidebar.

Normally it should look like this.

[image: normal]

But I am getting this.

[image: anormal]

There is other draw. And you can see the problem

[image]

When I include my `main` fragment beginning of my page it can't reach the `id=page-wrapper` because `page-wrapper` has to inside of `wrapper` element. But in my case it hasn't into `wrapper` element.

It can't align to left. How can I iclude my main fragment correctly for this.

Correct html.

```
<div th:fragment="main">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">            
    </nav>
    <div id="page-wrapper">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My html.

```
<div th:fragment="main">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">            
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="page-wrapper">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `page-wrapper` under `wrapper` and made `class = "container-fluid"` and solved my problem.